# How can I calculate a polynomial trend line where `y` always increases as `x` increases?

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions

Assume the following given coordinates: `[0,0],[12,200],[24,2000]`.

The following equation generates a second order polynomial trend line (at least that's what excel tells me) :

```
y = 800x^2 - 2200x + 1400
```

However, between 0 and 12 on the x axis, the y values are negative.

How can I calculate a trend line where the values of y always increase as x increases?

Answer (score 0):

If your trend line *must* go through those points, then you're probably stuck.  If you just want a "trend line" that gives the "general trend", then plot a literal *line*.  That is, tell Excel to give you a linear fit, $y=mx+b$, no quadratic term.